# Customize DevExpress chart control - inverted value in legend

Tags: wpf, charts, devexpress

I would like show chart control (Pie2D) with inverted value in legend.

Example picture:

[image]

My Class:

```
public class Foo
{
 string Name {get; set;}
 double Value { get; set; } 
 bool IsInverted { get; set; } 
}
```

And examples data:

```
"First", 20.0, false
"Second, -20.0, true //display "20" in chart, and -20 in legend
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: May be you can write a converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use the class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public string DiagramName { get { return string.Format("{0}: {1}", Name, Value); } }
    public double DiagramValue { get { return Math.Abs(Value); } }
}
```

Just bind argument and value data members to `DiagramName` and `DiagramValue` and make sure that all your paterns are using this format:

```
<SomeObject SomePattern="{}{A}" ... />
```

Here is example:

0. XAML:

```
<dx:DXWindow.Resources>
    <dx:IEnumerableDataSource x:Key="IEnumerableDataSource">
        <dx:DesignDataManager.DesignData>
            <dx:DesignDataSettings DataObjectType="{x:Type local:Foo}" RowCount="5"/>
        </dx:DesignDataManager.DesignData>
    </dx:IEnumerableDataSource>
</dx:DXWindow.Resources>

<Grid>

    <dxc:ChartControl x:Name="Chart" DataSource="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource IEnumerableDataSource}}">
        <dxc:ChartControl.Legend>
            <dxc:Legend />
        </dxc:ChartControl.Legend> 
        <dxc:ChartControl.Titles>
            <dxc:Title Content="Pie Chart" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </dxc:ChartControl.Titles>
        <dxc:SimpleDiagram2D>
            <dxc:PieSeries2D LabelsVisibility="True" ArgumentDataMember="DiagramName" ValueDataMember="DiagramValue" LegendTextPattern="{}{A}" ToolTipPointPattern="{}{A}">
                <dxc:PieSeries2D.Label>
                    <dxc:SeriesLabel TextPattern="{}{A}" />
                </dxc:PieSeries2D.Label>
            </dxc:PieSeries2D>
        </dxc:SimpleDiagram2D>
    </dxc:ChartControl>

</Grid>
```

1. Chart control data source:

```
var list = new List<Foo>();

list.Add(new Foo() { Name = "A", Value = -20 });
list.Add(new Foo() { Name = "B", Value = 80 });

Chart.DataSource = list;
```

2. Result:

[image: Result]